# group dictionary by values, return key and value list pair

Tags: python

Considering a dictionary with several recurring values. How to group the dictionary by value? For example:

```
mydict = 
{
    'germany': 'europe', 
    'france': 'europe',
    'canada': 'north america', 
    'latvia': 'europe'
    'usa': 'north america',
    'china': 'asia'
}
```

Group by value into list.

```
groupdDict =
{
    'europe': ['germany','france','latvia'],
    'north america': ['canada','usa'],
    'asia': ['china']
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.defaultdict`

**Demo:**

```
mydict ={
        'germany': 'europe',
        'france': 'europe',
        'canada': 'north america',
        'latvia': 'europe',
        'usa': 'north america',
        'china': 'asia'
    }

import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for k,v in mydict.items():
    d[v].append(k)
print(d)
```

*Or using a simple Iteration*

**Demo:**

```
d = {}
for k,v in mydict.items():
    if v not in d:
        d[v] = []
    d[v].append(k)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{'north america': ['canada', 'usa'], 'europe': ['france', 'latvia', 'germany'], 'asia': ['china']}
```